# Browse button used in <Control type ="" > to install .cer file in custom dialog using wix

Tags: wix, customdialog

I did not find type in control to browser and upload file in custom dialog in wix.

Type="PathEdit" browse the folder only , can not select file.

Comment: Such functionality is not supported by Windows Installer directly.

Answer (score 0):

I got very good help for browsing the file and getting file path.
Example provided with the sample code, just build the dll with "MSBUILD "

Refer the link for more details: [WiX Managed Custom Actions (OpenFileDialog Example)](http://community.saasgrid.com/developers/b/team/archive/2011/02/17/wix-managed-custom-actions-openfiledialog-example.aspx).